# How do I parse a string based on a certain number of characters in the string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, string-parsing

I know how to parse a string based on a delimiter, such as a comma. Does this require turning the string into an array of char?

I am wanting to compare a string that is 6 numebrs i.e. 111222

with another string of numbers that is 12 characters long but I only want the first six.

Basically way to check that 111222 occurs in the string 111222345678.

Comment: Keep in mind that checking the first few characters of a string and checking whether a string is contained in another string are two different problems. Other than that you should be able to use google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *....but I only want the first six*

For first `n` chars comparison you can use [*`std::strncmp`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncmp)

```
char s1[] ="111222345678" ;
char s2[] ="111222";

std::cout << std::strncmp( s1,s2, 6 ) ; // n =6 chars
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, it never occurred to just compare the string as a whole instead of cutting off the last 6 chars of the 12 number string. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

using std::string, you could do

```
std::string sample = "111222345678";

if (sample.substr(0, 6) == "111222")
{
   ... do stuff here if ... 
}
```

Of course, this can be made more generic by having the string to match as a `std::string` too:

```
std::string match = "111222";
if (sample.substr(0, match.length()) == match))
{
  ... 
}
```

Comment: Maybe not quite as simple, but I'd use something like `if ( sample.size() >= match.size() && std::equal( match.begin(), match.end(), sample.begin() )`.